# Async functions not being recognized

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, asynchronous, async-await

I have some async functions that I have used in multiple projects, however when I added them to another project they suddenly aren't working.

An example of one of these functions is:

```
const ddbGet = async (params) => {
    try {
        const data = await docClient.get(params).promise();
        return data;
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("Failure", err.message);
        return false;
    }
};
```

The error that gets thrown is:

```
const ddbGet = async (params) => {

                     ^
```

SyntaxError: Unexpected token (

However I know there are no problems with the functions' syntax as they are used successfully elsewhere.

I have seen some answers to other questions that have suggested some issues with JSHint and ESLint however I don't believe I was using either of these, but just to be sure I installed ESLint and specified the ECMA version as suggested in those answers and this error was still thrown.

I have also made sure I'm using the latest version of Node.js.

And if I remove those functions an error gets thrown due to an asynchronous function in the node_modules folder.

`async handshake(transportName, req, closeConnection) {`

```
   `^^^^^^^^^`
```

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Does anybody know what the problem could be? Thanks.

Comment: What does `node -v` tell you? Your problem is clearly that your JavaScript platform is dated for some reason.

Comment: What is throwing the error? The browser? The build?

Comment: The example code doesn't throw any errors in [eslint](https://eslint.org/demo)

Comment: @Pointy v17.2.0, I installed the latest version when the error was first thrown hoping it would solve it! Sadly it didn't

Comment: @epascarello The build. I'm using an AWS Cloud9 environment if that helps

Comment: If you're using an IDE (for example WebStorm, as I only know for it), be sure that the config aren't mixed up in .idea. You could very well have an old NodeJS interpreter for one project and the newest one for another. Be sure to re-do the configs if you're running your script via said IDE. EDIT: Last comment of OP made mine pretty useless but keeping it for others that might come across this problem.

Comment: @UdoE. its the first parenthese before the params argument

Comment: Since you mentionned `AWS Cloud9`, I assume you followed their "Getting Started". What does `nvm ls` output?

Comment: @GaëtanBoyals This isn't a new project, it's actually 4 years old or so and I've inherited it so I wasn't involved in the set up.

Comment: @GaëtanBoyals  nvm ls gave me this output: 
v6.15.1  
->      v17.2.0  
         system  
default -> 6 (-> v6.15.1)
node -> stable (-> v17.2.0) (default)
stable -> 17.2 (-> v17.2.0) (default)
iojs -> N/A (default)
lts/* -> lts/argon (-> N/A)
lts/argon -> v4.9.1 (-> N/A)
lts/boron -> v6.17.1 (-> N/A)
lts/carbon -> v8.17.0 (-> N/A)
lts/dubnium -> v10.24.1 (-> N/A)
lts/erbium -> v12.22.9 (-> N/A)
lts/fermium -> v14.18.3 (-> N/A)
lts/gallium -> v16.13.2 (-> N/A)

Comment: Gotcha, I'm writing a full answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution with a little more research after Gaëtan Boyals put me on the right path!

He was correct that the default version of Node.js was the issue and the solution to fix this was `nvm alias default 17.2.0`

Comment: Great! Glad I could at least help!

Comment: @GaëtanBoyals Yes thank you! I'll upvote your answer as it was still helpful to me :)

Answer (score 2):

Since the documentation, or rather AWS Cloud9's [Getting Started](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloud9/latest/user-guide/sample-nodejs.html) isn't kept up-to-date (using an old script to install NVM) and seeing that the project was very old (as per the extended comment section of the question), it surely was the NodeJS version.

This is confirmed by the `nvm ls` output the OP gave us (I only formatted it):

```
v6.15.1
-> v17.2.0 system
default -> 6 (-> v6.15.1)
node -> stable (-> v17.2.0) (default)
stable -> 17.2 (-> v17.2.0) (default)
iojs -> N/A (default)
lts/* -> lts/argon (-> N/A) 
lts/argon -> v4.9.1 (-> N/A) 
lts/boron -> v6.17.1 (-> N/A) 
lts/carbon -> v8.17.0 (-> N/A) 
lts/dubnium -> v10.24.1 (-> N/A) 
lts/erbium -> v12.22.9 (-> N/A) 
lts/fermium -> v14.18.3 (-> N/A) 
lts/gallium -> v16.13.2 (-> N/A)
```

The line `default -> 6 (-> v6.15.1)` informs us that the default NodeJS version used (for the whole system) is `v6.15.1`.

Unfortunately, NodeJS does **NOT** handle async/await syntax natively before `v7.6`.

You could run `nvm install 17.2.0` and then `nvm use 17.2.0` (or simply the `nvm use` part, but I don't know if the `v17.2.0` we see in the output have effectively been installed via NVM), which is likely to fix this particular problem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I shall try this when I return to the office tomorrow morning :)

Comment: Sure, keep me updated!

Comment: This is was the output after the `nvm use 17.2.0` command: Now using node v17.2.0 (npm v8.3.0)

Comment: I've found the solution thanks to your guidance, posting it now